# C# WPF Expander IsExpand reacts only once

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, expand

im using following Expander Style for multiple Items in a Listview:

```
<Style x:Key="ExpanderRightHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                    <Grid Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="False">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="19"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.LayoutTransform>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <TransformGroup.Children>
                                        <TransformCollection>
                                            <RotateTransform Angle="-90"/>
                                        </TransformCollection>
                                    </TransformGroup.Children>
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </Grid.LayoutTransform>
                            <Ellipse x:Name="circle" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="19" Stroke="DarkGray" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="19"/>
                            <Path x:Name="arrow" Data="M 1,1.5 L 4.5,5 L 8,1.5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" SnapsToDevicePixels="false" Stroke="#666" StrokeThickness="2" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,4,0,0" Grid.Row="1" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Data" TargetName="arrow" Value="M 1,4.5  L 4.5,1  L 8,4.5"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="#FF3C7FB1"/>
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="#222"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="#FF526C7B"/>
                        <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" TargetName="circle" Value="1.5"/>
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="#FF003366"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="ExpanderUpHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                    <Grid Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="False">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="19"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.LayoutTransform>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <TransformGroup.Children>
                                        <TransformCollection>
                                            <RotateTransform Angle="180"/>
                                        </TransformCollection>
                                    </TransformGroup.Children>
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </Grid.LayoutTransform>
                            <Ellipse x:Name="circle" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="19" Stroke="DarkGray" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="19"/>
                            <Path x:Name="arrow" Data="M 1,1.5 L 4.5,5 L 8,1.5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" SnapsToDevicePixels="false" Stroke="#666" StrokeThickness="2" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4,0,0,0" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Data" TargetName="arrow" Value="M 1,4.5  L 4.5,1  L 8,4.5"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="#FF3C7FB1"/>
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="#222"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="#FF526C7B"/>
                        <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" TargetName="circle" Value="1.5"/>
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="#FF003366"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="ExpanderLeftHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                    <Grid Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="False">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="19"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.LayoutTransform>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <TransformGroup.Children>
                                        <TransformCollection>
                                            <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
                                        </TransformCollection>
                                    </TransformGroup.Children>
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </Grid.LayoutTransform>
                            <Ellipse x:Name="circle" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="19" Stroke="DarkGray" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="19"/>
                            <Path x:Name="arrow" Data="M 1,1.5 L 4.5,5 L 8,1.5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" SnapsToDevicePixels="false" Stroke="#666" StrokeThickness="2" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,4,0,0" Grid.Row="1" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Data" TargetName="arrow" Value="M 1,4.5  L 4.5,1  L 8,4.5"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="#FF3C7FB1"/>
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="#222"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="#FF526C7B"/>
                        <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" TargetName="circle" Value="1.5"/>
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="#FF003366"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="ExpanderHeaderFocusVisual">
    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Border>
                    <Rectangle Margin="0" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="ExpanderDownHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                    <Grid Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="False">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="19"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Ellipse x:Name="circle" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="19" Stroke="Yellow" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="19"/>
                        <Path x:Name="arrow" Data="M 1,1.5 L 4.5,5 L 8,1.5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" SnapsToDevicePixels="false" Stroke="#666" StrokeThickness="2" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4,0,0,0" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Data" TargetName="arrow" Value="M 1,4.5  L 4.5,1  L 8,4.5"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="#FF3C7FB1"/>
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="#222"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="#FF526C7B"/>
                        <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" TargetName="circle" Value="1.5"/>
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="#FF003366"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="ExpanderOwnDownHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                    <Grid Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="False">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="14"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid Grid.Column="0" Width="14" Height="14">
                            <Rectangle Fill="{DynamicResource primaryBackgroundBrush}" />
                            <Border Name="ExpandBorder" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" BorderBrush="{StaticResource BrushSelection}" BorderThickness="2">
                                <Path RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" Name="ExpandPath" Stroke="{StaticResource BrushSelection}" Margin="0" StrokeThickness="2" Data="M 5 1 L 5 9 M 1 5 L 9 5" />
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                        <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4,0,0,0" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Data" TargetName="ExpandPath" Value="M 1 5 L 9 5"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <!--<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Data" TargetName="ExpandPath" Value="M 1 5 L 9 5"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Data" TargetName="ExpandPath" Value="M 1 5 L 9 5"/>
                    </Trigger>-->
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>


<Style TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
                <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="3" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <DockPanel>
                        <ToggleButton x:Name="HeaderSite" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplateSelector}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}" FocusVisualStyle="{StaticResource ExpanderHeaderFocusVisual}" FontStyle="{TemplateBinding FontStyle}" FontStretch="{TemplateBinding FontStretch}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="1" MinWidth="0" MinHeight="0" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Style="{StaticResource ExpanderDownHeaderStyle}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                         IsChecked="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ExpandSite" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Focusable="false" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </DockPanel>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="ExpandSite" Value="Visible"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="ExpandSite" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="ExpandDirection" Value="Right">
                        <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="ExpandSite" Value="Left"/>
                        <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="Right"/>
                        <Setter Property="Style" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="{StaticResource ExpanderRightHeaderStyle}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="ExpandDirection" Value="Up">
                        <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="ExpandSite" Value="Top"/>
                        <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="Bottom"/>
                        <Setter Property="Style" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="{StaticResource ExpanderUpHeaderStyle}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="ExpandDirection" Value="Left">
                        <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="ExpandSite" Value="Left"/>
                        <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="Right"/>
                        <Setter Property="Style" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="{StaticResource ExpanderLeftHeaderStyle}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="ExpandDirection" Value="Down">
                        <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="ExpandSite" Value="Bottom"/>
                        <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="Top"/>
                        <Setter Property="Style" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="{StaticResource ExpanderOwnDownHeaderStyle}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

In the Style Template for the ListView Items i have an expander and bind IsExpanded to a boolean in my ViewModel so i am able to expand all Items at once:

```
<Expander IsExpanded="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.ExpandAll, Mode=OneWay}">
```

In my view i have followig toggle button to expand all items:

```
<ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding ExpandAll, Mode=TwoWay}" Style="{StaticResource ExpanderOwnDownHeaderStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></ToggleButton>
```

Now when i start the application and expand all items this works fine but as soon as I expand a single item in the listview, the item no longer responds when I click on "expand all". From then on I can only open the item separately.

I have recorded a short video to better understand the problem.
https://www.veed.io/view/49f49679-f14b-4623-a8cd-41831503e045?panel=share

Any Ideas what the problem here is?

Update:
When im using the standard expander without any stlye template, the problem is the same.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem like the described in:
https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/4362

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).